# Kendo grid not showing proper value for null date field if arranged in required format?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried and googled lots of code but did not find any workable solution.

In the below code the column bound to the kendo grid may sometimes have null value at that time I need to show blank and all other times I need to show the date in {0:dd/MM/yyyy} format.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<GurujiWorld.GEMS.MVC.Models.Test.TestComplaint>()
     .Name("grid")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(p => p.ComplaintCloseDate)
              .EditorTemplateName("DateTimeEditor")
              .Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")
              .Title("Complaint Closed Date")
              .Width(100);
     }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Kendo grid not showing proper value for null date field if arranged in required format?

Comment: That's not helping. I'm guessing you want to display dates on a column but if the date for that record is null you don't want to show anything, right? What is currently happening? What happens for null values?

Comment: Kendo TreeLis is showing "null" instead of empty value.